# OBJLoader 404 error trying to load .obj file

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm trying to load a `.obj` from a folder in my computer and I'm receiving this error:
`GET http://localhost:5500/Objects/ocean.obj 404 (Not Found)`

My code segment for loading is the following:

```
// instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( );

// load a resource
loader.load
    (
      // resource URL
      '../Objects/ocean.obj',
      // Function when resource is loaded
      function (object){
        scene.add( object );
      }
    );
```

I saw someone saying it was an issue with *web.config* and stuff but I can't seem to fix the issue or find/modify the *web.config* file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you already tried using one of the approaches explained in this guide? https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: Yes. I currently use Live Server from VS Code and Im running things locally.

Comment: This looks like you're simply pointing to the wrong directory. Are you sure you it's not nested in a deeper folder?

Comment: I changed my directory to /Objects/ocean.obj and it still gave me the 404 Error

Comment: Any chances to demonstrate the problem with a [glitch](https://glitch.com/create-project) live example? This site allows to upload assets which is useful to show your issue.

Comment: Yes, I have created an account and changed the directories to match the Glitch site format. Here is the link to my demo https://glitch.com/edit/#!/summer-plum-cobalt